# how to match value in PHP array and then find key value?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have an array variable `$colorArray = array('red','white','blue');`

Suppose `$color = "red";`, how do I match the value of $color with $colorArray and then find the corresponding key value of "red"? After I find the key value of "red", I would then need to store the key value in another variable for other uses.

Comment: array_search() http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

```
$key = array_search($color, $colorArray);
```

To ensure you got a match, make sure you compare it to `FALSE` and not just *falsy*.

```
if ($key !== FALSE) {
   // Match made.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `array_search`: http://www.php.net/array_search

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), here's an example:

```
$key = array_search($color, $colorArray);
```

In your example, this would return 0.