# Search for value in array of associative arrays using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-7

How to find the array which contains `moo == 'gyu'`?

```
$arr = [
  ['moo' => 'abc', 'foo' => 1], ['moo' => 'gyu', 'foo' => 2] ...
]
```

I know that should be answered already but unfortunately I wasn't able to find an example.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to match both i.e. key and value of the array?

Comment: @Varun.Kumar I need to find an array by pair `key=='moo' , value==$something`

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi That doesn't seem to be similar at all. He knows the key is `-moo`.

Comment: If you are sure about the value then you can refer this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488422/how-to-match-value-in-php-array-and-then-find-key-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to to find target array. In callback function check value of `moo` index.

```
$newArr = array_filter($arr, function($item){
    return $item['moo'] == 'gyu';
});
```

Also you can use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) that return target array in result.

```
$newArr = array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $item){
    $item['moo'] == 'gyu' ? $carry = $item : "";
    return $carry;
 });
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/QUVRm)

Answer (score 1):

You have to used array_search() function for that.

```
if(array_search('gyu', array_column($arr, 'moo')) !== False) {
    echo "FOUND";
} else {
    echo "Not Found";
 }
```